# How to implement cartesian product of n array with different lenghts in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

let's say that i have the following array:

```
data[size] = Array('s', 'm');
data[color] = Array('blue', 'red');
```

I need a function that outputs me the following array

```
variations[] = Array('s', 'blue');
variations[] = Array('s', 'red');
variations[] = Array('m', 'blue');
variations[] = Array('m', 'red');
```

The function must work also on arrays like:

```
data[size] = Array('s', 'm', 'l');
data[color] = Array('blue', 'red');
data[version] = Array('run', 'walk');
```

It should give an array like

```
variations[] = Array('s', 'blue', 'run');
variations[] = Array('s', 'blue', 'walk');
variations[] = Array('s', 'red', 'run');
variations[] = Array('s', 'red', 'walk');
```

And so on ...

How can i implement it?

p.s.: if there is a specific name for this problem let me know so i'll edit the question title for future use

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: That syntax is not valid JS. It seems PHP.

Comment: How you implement it begins with showing some effort at implementing it yourself

Comment: "How can I loop over two arrays and add their elements to a different array" is your starting point. Go and learn about loops.

Comment: do you want a simple implementation?for example two cases .data lenght = 2 or 3 as input?

Comment: thanks Hunter McMillen; what i need is an implementation of a function that can return as an array the Cartesian Product of n arrays with different lenghts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works having n arrays:

```
function cartesianProduct(data) {

    var current = [[]];
    for (var p in data) {
        var arr = data[p];
        var newCurrent = [];
        for (var c = 0; c < current.length; c++) {
            var baseArray = current[c];
            for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
                var clone = baseArray.slice();
                clone.push(arr[a]);
                newCurrent.push(clone);
            }
        }
        current = newCurrent;
    }

    return current;
}
```

for the following data:

```
var data = {
    size: ['s', 'm'],
    color: ['blue', 'red'],
    version: ['run', 'walk', 'jump']
};
```

will return all the combinations:

```
var variations = [
    ["s","blue","run"],
    ["s","blue","walk"],
    ["s","blue","jump"],
    ["s","red","run"],
    ["s","red","walk"],
    ["s","red","jump"],
    ["m","blue","run"],
    ["m","blue","walk"],
    ["m","blue","jump"],
    ["m","red","run"],
    ["m","red","walk"],
    ["m","red","jump"]
];
```

Comment: thank you Enrique! This perfectly solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is no valid JS, it seems PHP.

I assume you have

```
var data = {
    size: ['s', 'm'],
    color: ['blue', 'red']
};
```

And you want

```
var variations = [
    ['s', 'blue'],
    ['s', 'red'],
    ['m', 'blue'],
    ['m', 'red']
];
```

To get that, you can use

```
var variations = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.size.length; ++i)
    for (var j=0; j<data.color.length; ++j)
        variations.push([data.size[i], data.color[j]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried something fancy, working on local :

```
var variations = []
var str = "";
var ind = 0;
index = [];

for (var k in data)
{
    index[index.length] = k;
    str+="for(var i"+ind+" in data["+k+"])";
    ind++;
}
str += "{variations[variations.length] = [";
for (;ind >= 0; ind--)
{
    str+="data["+index[ind]+"][i"+ind+"]";
    if (ind > 0) str += ",";
    else str+="];";
}
str+= "}";

eval(str);
```

This allows to have any number of arrays in data =)